# fullcalendar doesn't show events

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar

i want to add some event to the fullcalendar.
A webmethod in aspx generate a json to the js
But i can't link the result of the web method with the full calendar,
I just can add manuals events.

the js :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btnInit').click(function () {
    var start = Date.parse($("#MainContent_dateD").text());
    var end = Date.parse($("#MainContent_dateF").text());
    var cle = $("#MainContent_HF_cleU").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ConsultationPlanning.aspx/getPlanning",
        data: '{"start": "' + start + '", "end": "' + end + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg == null) {
                alert('no result');
                return;
            }
            alert("received: " + msg.d);
            document.getElementById("MainContent_dateD").innerHTML = msg.d;
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                eventSources: JSON.parse(msg.d)
            });
        },
        error: function(msg){
            alert("marche pas : " + msg);
        }
    });
});

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    hiddenDays: [0],
    defaultView: 'month',
    editable: false,
    allDaySlot: false,
    selectable: false,
    eventSources: [{
        url: 'ConsultationPlanning.aspx/getPlanning'
    }]
});})
```

firstly, parameters in this webmethods were String
and the aspx.cs :

```
    public static String getPlanning(string start, string end)
    {
        List<String> ls1 = new List<string>();
        IList<Planning> ls2= new List<Planning>();

        DateTime t = Convert.ToDateTime(start);
        DateTime t2 = t.AddHours(1.0);
        Planning p=new Planning();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            p.id = "" + i + "" ;
            p.title = "event "+i ;
            p.start = String.Format("{0:s}", t.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(i)));
            p.end = String.Format("{0:s}", t2.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(i)));
            ls2.Add(p);
        }
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(ls2);
        return sJSON;
    }
```

I check the json file into jsonlint.com and it's validate, so i guess the mistake is in the js, but i don't see where.

and the json :

```
    [
    {"id":"0","title":"event 0","start":"2015-05-04T12:35:37","end":"2015-05-04T13:35:37"},
    {"id":"1","title":"event 1","start":"2015-05-05T12:35:37","end":"2015-05-05T13:35:37"},
    {"id":"2","title":"event 2","start":"2015-05-06T12:35:37","end":"2015-05-06T13:35:37"},
    {"id":"3","title":"event 3","start":"2015-05-07T12:35:37","end":"2015-05-07T13:35:37"}]
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the JSON feed returned by the server?

Comment: Refer to my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092190/populating-events-in-full-calender-javascript-from-the-database/30092608#30092608

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calendar never correctly load datas because, it was firstly load in the full calendar without events. and, i guess i should make a addEventSource...
After have move the call in the document.ready(function),
the solution was to get the result of the json in an event instead of the eventSource :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var start = Date.parse($("#MainContent_dateD").text());
var end = Date.parse($("#MainContent_dateF").text());
var cle = $("#MainContent_HF_cleU").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ConsultationPlanning.aspx/getPlanning",
    data: '{"start": "' + start + '", "end": "' + end + '"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (msg) {
        if (msg == null) {
            alert('no result');
            return;
        }

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            hiddenDays: [0],
            defaultView: 'month',
            editable: false,
            allDaySlot: false,
            selectable: false,
            events: JSON.parse(msg.d)
        });
    },

    error: function(msg){
        alert("function not working : " + msg);
    }
});
})
```

i don't close the subject now, if you have any suggestion to make the code better.

Answer (score 0):

Add `events: [<%=getPlanning%>]` and remove `eventSources`.

Comment: javascript doesn't want : [<%=getPlanning%>],
But i change enventSources by events and it works when i click and when the calendar isn't load firstly. I'm close to make it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: While this source code may provide an answer, a few words of explanation would benefit current and future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code to get only events in the given range, then, the callback should do the magic:

```
eventSources: {
    events: function (start, end, callback) {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "ConsultationPlanning.aspx/getPlanning",
           data: '{ "start": "' + start.toISOString() + '", "end": "' + end.toISOString() + '" }',
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (msg) {
               callback(msg.d);
           } 
        }
    }
}
```

To make it work, you have to replace the signature of your server method with DateTime parameters...

Comment: Do you think the mistake came from the date format? I can read them with the webservice and manage them...
But, the callback make page bug.