# Fullcalendar not showing up events - PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I am using the Full calendar in my PHP application. But the issue is that events don't show up in the calendar.

Calendar.php -

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";  
$user = "myusername";
$pw = "mypass";
$database = "mydb";

$db = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw)
    or die("Cannot connect to mySQL.");

mysql_select_db($database,$db)
    or die("Cannot connect to database.");


$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');

$command = "SELECT * FROM `calendar_urls` ";
$result = mysql_query($command, $db);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $url =  $row['calendar_array'];
    $urls[] = $url;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' media='print' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        editable: true,

        //events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/kelchuk68%40gmail.com/public/basic/',

        eventSources: [
        //get_string(),
        /*'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/kelchuk68%40gmail.com/public/basic',
        'events.php',*/
        <?php echo implode(",", $urls); ?>
        ]
    });
}); 
</script>
<style type='text/css'>

    body {
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    }

    #calendar {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="display:block; width:900px; margin: 0 auto; ">
<div style="float:right; margin-bottom:10px;">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]; ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="add_event" value="Add Event"/>
</form>
<p style="display:none">Add Event | Edit Event | Delete Event</p></div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>


<?php if($_POST['add_event']){
$year = date("Y"); 
$year2= $year + 1;
$mymonth = date("m"); 
$day = date("d");?>
<div style="background-color:grey; width:900px; margin:0 auto;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:10px; border-radius:15px;">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]; ?>" method="post">
<div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">Title: <input style="margin:0 auto; text-align:left;" type="text" name="event_title" value=""/>
<select name ="year">
<?php echo '<option selected="selected">'.$year.'</option>';
echo '<option>'.$year2.'</option>';

echo '</select>';
?>

<select name ="month">
<?php 
$month = array($month);
echo '<option selected="selected">'.$mymonth.'</option>';
$months = array('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12');
$months = array_diff($months,$month);

foreach($months as $month_opt){
echo '<option>'.$month_opt.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

?>

<select name="day">
<?php echo '<option selected="selected">'.$day.'</option>';
for($i=1; $i<32; $i++) {
echo '<option>'.$i.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
?>
&nbsp Hour: <select name="hour">
<?php 
$hours = array('00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23');

foreach($hours as $hour){
echo '<option>'.$hour.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';

?>
&nbsp Minutes: <select name="minutes">
<?php 
$minutes = array('00','15','30','45');

foreach($minutes as $minute){
echo '<option>'.$minute.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
echo'</div>';
?><br/><br/>
<div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:5px;">Notes:</div>
<textarea name="notes" style="width:880px; margin:0 auto;"></textarea><br/>

<?php
echo '<input style="margin-top:10px;" type="submit" name="adding" value="Add the Event"/></form></div><br/><br/>';
} 

if($_POST['adding']) {
$year = $_POST['year'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day= $_POST['day'];
$hour= $_POST['hour'];
$minutes= $_POST['minutes'];
$fulldate = $year."-".$month."-".$day." ".$hour.":".$minutes;

$command = "INSERT INTO calendar VALUES('','0', '{$_POST['event_title']}', '{$_POST['notes']}', '$fulldate','') ";
$result = mysql_query($command, $db);
if($result) {
echo "Successful Insert!";
}
}
?>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The calendar shows up properly. Also it lets user add events but those events are not displayed.
The 2 tables which are used by the calendar contain the following -

[image]

[image]

This is my events.php-

```
<?php

session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
include ("connect.inc");
$db = public_db_connect();
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');

$command = "SELECT * FROM `calendar`";
$result = mysql_query($command, $db);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //echo "hi";
    //$start = date("D, j M Y G:i:s T", strtotime($row['start']));
    //$end = date("D, j M Y G:i:s T", strtotime($row['end_time']));
    $start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['start']));
    //$start = "$year-$month-20";
    $myid =  $row['id'];
    $eventsArray['id'] =  (int)trim($myid);
    $eventsArray['title'] = $row['title'];
    $title = date("g:ia", strtotime($row['start']))." ".$row['title'];

    //$title = $row['title'];
    //echo $title;
    $eventsArray['title'] = $title;
    $eventsArray['start'] = $start;
    /*$eventsArray['end'] = $start;*/
    $eventsArray['url'] = "edit_calendar.php?calendarid=".$row['id'];

    // $eventsArray['end'] = $end;
    // $eventsArray['allDay'] = false;
    $events[] = $eventsArray;
}
echo json_encode($events);
```

Connect.inc -

```
<?php
function public_db_connect() {

    $host = "localhost";  
    $user = "myuser";
    $pw = "mypass";
    $database = "mydb";

    $db = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw)
       or die("Cannot connect to mySQL.");

    mysql_select_db($database,$db)
       or die("Cannot connect to database.");

    return $db;
}
?>
```

I don't know what that calendar URL is for and why it has some google link as it came from the site I downloaded this calendar.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems you haven't read the documents carefully. Everything is clear there. it depends on you what kind of events you want to show either google or yours. and stop using `mysql_*` it is deprecated

Comment: Ok. I may have not read it. Can you please guide me here or can u provide the documentation link if possible ? It would be great. thanks.

Comment: check my answer here, it might help -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092190/populating-events-in-full-calender-javascript-from-the-database/30092608#30092608

Comment: There are multiple ways to push events into your calendar. you are using `eventSources` method. This method is used fetch events from different urls that you can pass into this. and those urls contains the events in json format.