# JS, fullcalendar, the "events" parameter doesn't get the result of an executed function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, jquery-callback

answer : the mistake was not in the synchronous or asynchronous call but in utilisation of functions set by the fullcalendar.
    events: function(start,end,**timezone**,callback){...}

I can see informations switch how i manage the result of the ajax (sjax...) but the calendar doesn't get the information.

It seems the line "events : getJSON," doesn't work. But the function is call

Now, i have a new problem, the function getJSON get the JSON from the webmethod, but the calendar doesn't show them.

I tried to get the result with the commented code also, but it doesn't work.

here are both methods froms the js :

```
function getJSON() {
    start = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').format();
    duration = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getCalendar').moment().format();
    alert(start);
    var retour;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: "ConsultationPlanning.aspx/getPlanning",
        data: '{"start": "' + start + '", "end": "' + duration + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            retour = JSON.parse(msg.d);
            retour = msg.d;
        },
        error: function () { alert("erreur");}
    });
    alert(retour);
    return retour;
};

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    hiddenDays: [0],
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    editable: false,
    allDaySlot: false,
    selectable: false,
    events: getJSON,
        /*function (start, end, callback) {
        start = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').format();
        duration = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getCalendar').moment().format();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "ConsultationPlanning.aspx/getPlanning",
            data: '{"start": "' + start + '", "end": "' + end + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                var rdv = [];
                alert(msg.d);
                //var events =JSON.parse(msg.d);
                $(msg.d).each(function () {
                    rdv.push({
                        id: $(this).attr('id'),
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),
                        start: $(this).attr('start'),
                    })
                })
                alert("first date : " + rdv[0].start);
                //"first date: 2015-05-06T14:33:00" is what i get
                callback(rdv);
                //the callback generate an error message. it says, it's waiting for a function

            }
        })
    }
});
```

i posted a similar question few days ago, but it was with an other implementation:

[fullcalendar doesn't show events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027685/fullcalendar-doesnt-show-events/30031322#30031322)

Comment: it will work, please refer to my answer in this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092190/populating-events-in-full-calender-javascript-from-the-database/30092608#30092608

Comment: call it as a function events: getJSON()

Comment: when i call the function with parentheses, i can't use "$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').format();" ine the function getJSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.ajax` triggers an asynchronous call ; the value of your `retour` variable will be set to the value you expect only after your browser has received the response to its request.

That's why fullcalendar's `events` is called with a `callback` argument :

```
function getJSON(start, end, callback) {
    ...
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success : function(msg) {
            retour = JSON.parse(msg.d);
            callback(retour);
        }
    });
    // no need to return anything here
}
```

See the doc for fullcalendar v1.* here : [events function](http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/events_function/)

---

Note : if you are using fullcalendar v2 or higher, you should change your function signature to :

```
function getJSON(start, end, timezone, callback) {
     ...
```

see doc for v2.* here : [events function](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/)

Comment: thank you very much, i am using the fullcalendar v2 and i thought i could run the function without the timezone.
And i just add the parameter without use it and it works.
If i could, i click on the arrow to say your answer is usefull in my case.
Further more, i uncomment my code and remove my function getJSON